# How come 'mary' is true twice?

Tags: prolog

I have a Prolog program that should return true for `pass(mary)` once, except mine returns twice and I am unsure why.

The program is designed to check whether a `Student` has passed their course. It checks:

- if the `Student` has a high enough `Mark` in their programming course,
- that they haven't failed an exam,
- to see if their average performance in their exams is above 40,
- if their coursework is above 50; if it isn't, then their average performance in their exams has to be 50 or above to pass.

With the facts I have, 'mary' passes (as she should), whilst others fail (as they also should), but 'mary' is true twice for some reason.

Facts (just 'mary'):

```
coursework(mary, 75).
programming(mary, 70).
e1(mary, 60).
e2(mary, 65).
e3(mary, 70).
marks(mary, [60, 65, 70]).
```

Code:

```
sum([], 0).
sum([X|Tail], Sum):-
  sum(Tail, Temp),
  Sum = Temp + X.

avg(List, Avg):-
  sum(List, Sum),
  length(List, Length),
  Length > 0,
  Avg is Sum / Length.

examFail(Student):-
  (  e1(Student, MarkE1),
     MarkE1 < 30
  ;  e2(Student, MarkE2),
     MarkE2 < 30
  ;  e3(Student, MarkE3),
     MarkE3 < 30
  ).

courseworkCheck(Student):-
  (  coursework(Student, Mark),
     Mark > 49
  ;  marks(Student, List),
     avg(List, Avg),
     Avg > 49
  ).

pass(Student):-
  programming(Student, Mark),
  Mark > 29,
  \+ examFail(Student),
  marks(Student, List),
  avg(List, Avg),
  Avg > 39,
  courseworkCheck(Student).
```

Is there something I am doing wrong?

Comment: Minor: `s/Sum = Temp + X./Sum is Temp + X./`

Comment: Yeah, I keep doing that. Cheers for noticing.

Answer (score 1):

Your program already succeeds for `pass(mary)`, if `courseworkCheck/1` is restricted to one of the alternatives. That is, both

```
courseworkCheck(Student):-
  (  coursework(Student, Mark),
     Mark > 49
  ;  marks(Student, List),
     avg(List, Avg),
     Avg > 49, false
  ).
```

and

```
courseworkCheck(Student):-
  (  coursework(Student, Mark),
     Mark > 49, false
  ;  marks(Student, List),
     avg(List, Avg),
     Avg > 49
  ).
```

succeed. Essentially, that is not a problem as such. The best would be to reduce overheads by wrapping `setof(t, courseworkCheck(Student), _)` or `setof(t,pass(Student),_)`. But rather use this device sparingly.

Otherwise, `Avg >= 50` is preferable to `Avg > 49`. After all, some day `Avg = 49.5` might occur....